# C bug with creating a substring - possibly a memory error?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-leaks, substring, token

I'm pretty new to C and was wondering if I could get some help! I've been working on this bug for +15 hours.

So, this program is a tokenizer.

Basically, the program is supposed to take a string, or "token stream," and break it up into "tokens." A "token" is a string of either a word, hexadecimal int, octal int, decimal int, floating point int, or symbol.

The code I'm posting is only the code where things go wrong, the other portion of my program is what creates the token.

The gist of how the below code works is this: It takes a "token stream", and then finds the next token from that stream. Once that is completed, it will create a substring of the "token stream" minus the new token, and return that as the new "token stream."

Essentially, when the string `"0x4356/*abdc 0777 */[]87656879jlhg kl(/j jlkh 'no thank you' /"` is passed through, the program will do everything properly except when `"jlhg kl(/j jlkh 'no thank you' /"` passes. Once that passes through my program, a `"jlhg"` token is created BUT then it is added to the *end* of the token stream again. So, the new token stream to be broken down becomes `" kl(/j jlkh 'no thank you' / jlhg"` where `jlhg` is added on at the end, where it wasn't there before. It does this same weird thing once more, right afterwards, but with `"kl"` instead.

It only does this under extremely weird conditions, so I'm not sure the cause. I put print statements throughout my program and things flow normally except seemingly out of no where, the program will just add those at the end. This I why I feel like it *might* be a memory problem, but I have absolutely no clue where to go from here.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!

EDIT: If you pass the string "array[xyz ] += pi 3.14159e-10 A12B" output should be:

word "array"

left brace "["

word "xyz"

right brace "]"

plusequals "+="

word "pi"

float "3.14159e-10"

word "A12B"

My TokenizerT is this:

```
struct TokenizerT_
{
    char *tokenType;
    char *token;
};

typedef struct TokenizerT_ TokenizerT;
```

Relevant code:

```
/*
* TKNewStream takes two TokenizerT objects. 
* It will locate the index of the end   of the last token, 
* and create a substring with the new string to be tokenized.
* @tokenStream: old token stream
* @newToken: new token created from old token stream
*
*/

char *TKGetNextStream(char *tokenStream, char *newToken)
{
    int i,
        index = 0,
        count = 0;

    char last = newToken[strlen(newToken)-1];

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(newToken); i++)
    {
        if(newToken[i] == last)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(tokenStream); i++)
    {
        if(tokenStream[i] == last && count == 1)
        {
            index = i + 1;
            break;
        }
        else if(tokenStream[i] == last)
        {
            count--;
        }
    }

    char *ret = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(tokenStream) - index));

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(tokenStream) - index; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = tokenStream[i+index];
    }

    return ret;
}

/*
* This is my main
*/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *string = "0x4356/*abdc 0777 */[]87656879jlhg kl(/j jlkh 'no thank you' /";

    TokenizerT *newToken = malloc(sizeof(struct TokenizerT_)),
               *tokenStream = malloc(sizeof(struct TokenizerT_));  

    tokenStream->token = string;

    while(newToken != NULL)
    {
        newToken = TKCreate(TKGetNextToken(tokenStream));

        if(newToken != NULL)
        {
            tokenStream->token = TKGetNextStream(tokenStream->token,
                                                 newToken->token);

            printf("%s \"%s\"\n",
                   newToken->tokenType,
                   newToken->token);
        }
    }

    TKDestroy(newToken);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is your original code so badly formatted? that will by itself make it hard to debug.

Comment: This `TokenizerT *firstTK = malloc(sizeof(struct TokenizerT_)), *newTK = malloc(sizeof(struct TokenizerT_)), *tmp;` is a really bad idea because, no one would expect a `malloc` call thre, and you are never checking the return value of your `malloc`'s.

Comment: @iharob badly formatted how? Like the structure of my code is bad? Like I said, I'm really new to C and to programming in general...

how do I check the return value of malloc?

Comment: please format your code, I did it for you and now you changed it, it's unreadable.

Comment: Use white space to make independent tokens clear, eyes are not compilers, and use consistent indentation.

Comment: @iharob thanks for the formatting help, I think it's better.

Comment: Why aren't you using strtok ?

Comment: @tomato From what I understand, strtok only breaks up strings when there are whitespaces separating them. I needed to break up tokens within tokens using specific parameters that I was given. For instance, in the above string, "0x4356/*abdc 0777 /[]87656879jlhg " would create the tokens "0x4356", "/*", "abdc", "0777", etc. So even if it isn't separated by a whitespace it can still be a separate token in my program.

Comment: `strtok()` breaks strings into tokens based on delimiters you specify.  Not only white space.  For example, char delim[] = {" ,.x\n\t"};  will break a string on any of the contained delimiters, " ", `,`, `.`, `x`, `\n`, `\t`

Comment: If you can provide what the result should look like, given your input string, it may be helpful to interpret what you are asking for.  Your use of the term ***token string*** is not clear, nor is it clear what a ***floating point int*** is.  Also, it would be helpful to know how you prvide the definition for `TokenizerT` struct.

Comment: @ryyker I edited the post and tried to clean up my code for ya.

Comment: You know this is what yacc/lex is for, right?

Comment: @abligh urr I don't know what yacc or lex is... but this is a project for a course

Comment: @ks1994 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc (though more commonly these days Flex + Bison). In essence these are tools that reliably build parsers and lexical analysers in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string created in `ret` isn't properly null terminated. So all the functions dealing with strings will assume it goes on until the next random zero byte that happens to be found after the allocated memory.

To fix this allocate one more byte of space for `ret` and set that to zero, or use an existing function like `strdup()` to copy the string:

```
ret = strdup(tokenStream + index);
```

Comment: I'm too new of a user to upvote your answer but this worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @kd1994 - i'll upclick it for you.